# Entry requirements to Dominican Republic for US F1 visa student

Tags: indian-citizens, visa-free-entry, dominican-republic

I am masters student with F1 visa status in the US. I am from India. Do I need to apply for visa to go for vacation to Dominican Republic?

Answer (score 1):

The [Embassy of the Dominican Republic in Washington, D.C.](http://www.domrep.org/visa.html) has this statement:

> **Who can enter the Dominican Republic with ONLY a tourist card for tourist purposes only?**
>
> Any person who can legally travel or reside in the United States, Canada and the European Union (including Great Britain) does not need a visa to visit the Dominican Republic for tourist purposes and can enter the Dominican Republic with a Tourist Card and a valid passport.

However, it then lists a bunch of countries that does not include India. I am assuming that the country list is for others who do not have a visa for the US, Canada or the EU/UK.

You can purchase a tourist card online for $10.00 via a link on the website given in the first sentence.

Comment: thanks for response, So do you mean I could travel without visa?

Comment: You can also buy the tourist card when you enter the country. Strange thing is that they charged me (and a whole airplane of tourists) another US$20 to leave the country!